# what will vector.size()-1 will return when vector is empty?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14

when a empty vector is created and the following operation is done i am getting wrong answer.

> vector.size() - `enter code here`1 on empty vector its returns 4294967295 but the answer is -1

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  vector<int> v;
  cout<<v.size()<<"\n";
  cout<<v.size() -1 <<"\n";
 
}
```

the expected output should be

0

-1

but what i am getting was

0

4294967295

i don't know what is going wrong, can anyone tell whats wrong and pls correct it

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector::size_type // returned by vector::size()
```

is an unsigned integer type, and so the value wraps around.

Answer (score 4):

The `v.size()` returns an unsigned type integer and when you subtract `1` from an unsigned type with a value of 0 will cause wrap-around effects.

It can be said that it's `size_t` type.

The number you got will be `4294967295` because the size of integer is `4` bytes, or 4^8 = `4294967296`

**1.** If you want to solve the problem, then you need to convert it into an integer:

```
auto val = static_cast<int>(v.size()) - 1;
```

**2.** Or, if you don't want to use a `static_cast<>`, you can do it normally:

```
auto val = int(v.size()) - 1;
```

But notice that it's unsafe because it does not use `dynamic_cast` implicitly.

Both of the above methods will result you the following after printing their values using `cout`:

```
-1
```

Comment: It's actually the size of a `size_t` that is 4 bytes (32 bits).   That is implementation specific though - the standard permits, but does not require, it to be 32 bits.   (In fact, IIRC, the only guarantee since C++11 is that `size_t` will not be less than 16 bits).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach to fix it -

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  vector<int> v;
  int n = v.size();
  cout<< n << endl;
  cout<< n-1 << endl;
 
}
```

Comment: You don't need a new variable. You can `static_cast<int>(v.size()) - 1`, but the range is usually different and smaller.

Comment: Why does it work?